# Initialising hash map via nested for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, hashmap, nested-loops

I want a hash map to store integers for the key and value. By using a nested for-loop I thought it should work. I seem to not fully understand the program flow in the nested loop. Below my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hMap = new HashMap<>();

    //initializing running variables here to reuse in "display hashmap" loop
    int key = 48;
    int values = 65;

    //set keys and values to hashmap via nested for-loop 
    for (key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
        for (values = 65; values < 91; values++) {
            hMap.put(key, values);
        }
    }
    
    //display hashmap via nested for-loop
    for (key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + hMap.get(key));
    }
  }
}
```

This is the **current** console output:

```
Key: 48, Value: 90
Key: 49, Value: 90
Key: 50, Value: 90
Key: 51, Value: 90
Key: 52, Value: 90
Key: 53, Value: 90
...
```

And this is the console output I want:

```
Key: 48, Value: 65
Key: 49, Value: 66
Key: 50, Value: 67
Key: 51, Value: 68
Key: 52, Value: 69
Key: 53, Value: 70
...
```

I know now that the inner for-loop runs until the end condition is met and hence overriding the variable `value`. But how can I achieve the expected console output as shown above?

Comment: why is my question being downvoted? I tried my best to be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop. You are trying to `put` all combinations of `key`s between 48 and 73 and `value`s between 65 and 90 in the Map, but only the last value for each key is kept, since a Map doesn't allow duplicate keys.

A single loop will do what you need :

```
int value = 65;
for (int key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
    hMap.put (key, value++);
}
```

Putting `value++` in the Map will put the current value of `value` in the Map and increment the `value` variable for the next iteration. It's equivalent to:

```
int value = 65;
for (int key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
    hMap.put (key, value);
    value++
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain the post increment operator in the context of the call to put()

Comment: Thank you very much Eran. This helped me a lot and leads exactly to the results I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
//set keys and values to hashmap via nested for-loop 
 int values = 65;
 for (key = 48; key < 74 && values < 91; key++) {
         hMap.put(key, values);
         values++;
 }
```

See the output [here](https://ideone.com/8OB0Qr)

> Key: 48, Value: 65
>   Key: 49, Value: 66
>   Key: 50, Value: 67
>   Key: 51, Value: 68
>   Key: 52, Value: 69
>   Key: 53, Value: 70
>   Key: 54, Value: 71
>   .........

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the loop. For each key your are repeating the put for all the values.

Add and output like this one :

```
for (key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
    for (values = 65; values < 91; values++) {
        hMap.put(key, values);
        System.out.println("put Key: " + key + ", Value: " + values);
    }
}
```

And you wil see your error :

```
put Key: 48, Value: 65
put Key: 48, Value: 66
put Key: 48, Value: 67
put Key: 48, Value: 68
put Key: 48, Value: 69
put Key: 48, Value: 70
put Key: 48, Value: 71
put Key: 48, Value: 72
put Key: 48, Value: 73
put Key: 48, Value: 74
put Key: 48, Value: 75
put Key: 48, Value: 76
put Key: 48, Value: 77
put Key: 48, Value: 78
put Key: 48, Value: 79
put Key: 48, Value: 80
put Key: 48, Value: 81
put Key: 48, Value: 82
put Key: 48, Value: 83
put Key: 48, Value: 84
put Key: 48, Value: 85
put Key: 48, Value: 86
put Key: 48, Value: 87
put Key: 48, Value: 88
put Key: 48, Value: 89
put Key: 48, Value: 90
put Key: 49, Value: 65
put Key: 49, Value: 66
put Key: 49, Value: 67
put Key: 49, Value: 68
put Key: 49, Value: 69
put Key: 49, Value: 70
...
```

The last value in the map for each key is always `90`

Try this :

```
for (key = 48; key < 74; key++) {
    hMap.put(key, values++);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Guillaume. This makes even clearer that the inner loop runs until the end condition is met and only then return to the outer loop.